# DIY solid core door?

Tags: doors, woodworking, mdf

I need to construct a solid core door for the knee wall attic in our new room.  Rather than purchasing a custom door, have people been successful in constructing a door from particleboard or MDF?  I have a doorknob borer from Harbor Freight for just such a possibility.  I'm thinking about cutting a 4'x8'x3/4" into two 2'x3' pieces and sandwiching two with liquid nails, then boring the knob and latch holes.

Comment: What's the question, exactly? Folks have been building solid doors for centuries. The material isn't particularly important.

Comment: The inspector would probably want to see a 10 minute fire rating on the door.  Not that we'll get to test it out on anything, but if it looks solid and is painted, my guess is that it'll pass.  I suppose I'm just checking if it's a valid method of making a solid door or not, or if there's another cheaper way.  This is just for a 2'x3' access door for the knee wall space.

Answer (score 1):

You won't get cheaper or easier than two layers of sheet lumber. Particle board is a common component in 30-minute fire doors (though they usually have a hardwood veneer).

I'd do just as you plan. Sand or route a bullnose all the way around and seal it with a couple coats of urethane, smoothing with steel wool between.